# Can two past tense morphemes be used in the same clause?

Tags: grammar

What is wrong in saying
"I didn't knew KCET was cancelled"?

My friend suggested that I say
"I didn't know KCET was cancelled".

Comment: No, There can only be one tense morpheme in one clause. If there is a tense morpheme (present or past tense), it  goes on the first auxiliary verb in the clause; if there are no auxiliary verbs in the clause, then it goes on the main (i.e, only) verb in the clause. It does **not** go on both the auxiliary and the main verb.

Comment: *"I didn't **knew** KCET was cancelled"* is wrong because it is the **infinitive** of the verb that always follows do/did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> No, There can only be one tense morpheme in one clause. If there is a tense morpheme (present or past tense), it  goes on the first auxiliary verb in the clause; if there are no auxiliary verbs in the clause, then it goes on the main (i.e, only) verb in the clause. It does **not** go on both the auxiliary and the main verb.